# SQLite statements with a variable number of parameters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sqlite, parameters

I'm writing GUI in MATLAB and using [`mksqlite`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mksqlite/). I have problem passing parameters to it.

The command is `mksqlite([ 'INSERT INTO ' , z , ' VALUES (?)' ], data);` where:

- `z = 'table name'`, `'table name'` is chosen from a listbox.
- `data` to insert comes from `inputdlg`.

The problem is with `?` parameters because different tables have a different number of columns. Does anybody know a way to declare `?` in a dynamic manner?

```matlab
a = get(handles.listbox1,'String');
b = get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
tabela=a{b};
disp(tabela);
mksqlite( 'param_wrapping', 1 );
mksqlite( 'result_type', 1 );
[results,colnames] = mksqlite(['SELECT * FROM  ',  tabela])
disp(results);
e=fieldnames(results);
v=size(e);
for r=1:v
  prompt={'Wprowadź '};
dlg_title = 'Wprowadź ';
num_lines = 1;
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines); 
imie=answer{1};
disp(imie);
t=answer{1};
data{r}=t;
disp(data);
z=a{b};
end;

mksqlite([ 'INSERT INTO ' , z , ' VALUES (?,?,?,?)' ], data); %// << this should be dynamic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is you should either create your `VALUES(...)` dynamically or obtain a predefined statement for every table case.

You could try using a `String`-to-`String` map where the keys are table names, and the values are the `VALUES` statements. This can be acheived in MATLAB using a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) object. Here's an example of what I mean:

Suppose your table names are `table_names = {'table1','table2','table3'};`, and let's assume these tables have 2, 3 and 4 fields respectively. The corresponding `VALUES` part of the SQL command would therefore be: `sql_values = {'VALUES (?,?)','VALUES (?,?,?)','VALUES (?,?,?,?)'};`

Now we build a `Map` out of these `String` combinations:

```
values_map = containers.Map(table_names,sql_values);
```

After building the `Map` you can use the table name which you get from the listbox (`a` in your code) and retrieve the correct `VALUES` statement:

```
vals_str = values_map(a);
```

---

Alternatively, you can have logic which determines the right amount of `?,` to put in the parentheses after `VALUES`:

```
switch a
  case 'table1'
    nVals = 2;
  case 'table2'
    nVals = 3;
  case 'table3'
    nVals = 4;
end

vals_str = ['VALUES (' repmat('?,',[1 nVals-1]) '?)'];
```

<sub><sub>Note: you can keep the different `vals_str` right in your cases without the need to build `Strings` during runtime. I personally like such a version less for reasons I can't explain.</sub></sub>

---

Finally, you use `vals_str` in your `mksqlite`:

```
mksqlite(['INSERT INTO ' z ' ' vals_str], data);
```